# 'int' object is not callable when calling function

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a function to plot some data I have but when running the code below with `Fpi(mud)` I get the TypeError: `'int' object is not callable`.

I have already made sure that the name Fpi is not defined as an integer anywhere so I don't understand the problem.

```
mud=np.array([0.0014700734999999996,
 0.0011840320799999997,
 0.0014232304799999995,
 0.0008501509799999997,
 0.0007235751599999999,
 0.0005770661399999999,
 0.0005581295999999999,
 0.00028703807999999994,
 0.00014850233999999998])

afij=np.array([1.0944,-1.0])

def Fpi(x,B=2.58,Fc=88,mu=0.77):
    return Fc*(1+ ((2*B*x)/(4*pi*Fc))**2(afij[0]+afij[1]*np.log((2*B*x)**2/mu2)))
```

If anyone could help I'd be grateful!

Comment: When I try to define `Fpi` using your function definition I get *SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character*, which is caused by the backslash after `1+`. So there probably is an earlier definition of `Fpi` that your function has not overridden because the `def` statement fails.

Comment: when yo don't find the error it is better to split a long operation among different lines and temporary results: in this way it becomes clear which line/operation is generating an error

Answer (score 1):

`return Fc*(1+ ((2*B*x)/(4*pi*Fc))**2(afij[0]+afij[1]*np.log((2*B*x)**2/mu**2)))`

The error lies in the above statement. If you cannot spot it, look again.

`((2*B*x)/(4*pi*Fc))**2(afij[0] ...)`

Can you see it now?

`(...)**2(afij[0] ...)`

How about now?

If not, then here comes the spoiler.

> You missed the operator to be added after the `2`. Python, is assuming `(...)**2` to be some method and you are calling it, however, it is just an int, and cannot be used as a method. Hence the error.

EDIT: Got rid off the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting the operations:

```
mud=np.array([0.0014700734999999996,
 0.0011840320799999997,
 0.0014232304799999995,
 0.0008501509799999997,
 0.0007235751599999999,
 0.0005770661399999999,
 0.0005581295999999999,
 0.00028703807999999994,
 0.00014850233999999998])

afij=np.array([1.0944,-1.0])

def Fpi(x,B=2.58,Fc=88,mu=0.77):
    temp2 = ((2*B*x)/(4*pi*Fc))**2
    temp1 = temp2 (afij[0]+afij[1]*np.log((2*B*x)**2/mu2))
    return Fc*(1+ temp1)
```

The problem is that after `temp2` you do not have any operation to be performed (in your original code it was right after the `**2`).